# Java doesn't show up in firefox plugins

Tags: firefox, java, plugins

I've just installed the newest java, because firefox blocks the old version. I used the tutorial from http://www.backtrack-linux.org/wiki/index.php/Java_Install
Because I had some trouble once, I knew that there are multiple library folders, so I linked into all mozilla plugin folders that there are.

```
/root/.mozilla/plugins
/usr/lib/firefox/plugins/
/usr/lib/firefox-addons
/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
/usr/lib64/mozilla/plugins
```

java -version returns

```
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

But when I go to firefox plugins, it's not listed. What do I need to do, so that firefox recognizes java?

Comment: you try some similar to `ln -sf /opt/java/jre1.7.0_05/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so  ~/.mozilla/plugins/` ?

Comment: I think you should install **IcedTea Java plugin** (a package without any special icons) through Software Center. When I installed it, all other Java’s got checked in my Software Center and Java listed in Firefox plugins as well.